# Convergence of random variable with random distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Let $x_n$ a sequence of real numbers. Let $Y_n$ be a sequence of random variables whose distribution depends on $x_n$. More explicitly, 
$$
P(Y_n = l) = f(x_n, l),
$$
for some function $f:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$.

Assume that if $x_n \to x$, then
$$
Y_n \to y
$$
in probability.

My questions is, if we replace $x_n$ by a sequence of random variables $X_n \to x$ in probability, do we still have
$$
Y_n \to y
$$
in probability?

---

My guess is that this is true. We can find a coupling $(X_n',X_n)$ such that $X_n' \sim X_n$ and $X_n' \to x$ almost surely.  Then we can let $Y_n$'s distribution depend on $X_n'$ instead. Now since the convergence of $X_n'$ to $x$ is almost surely, we can conclude that (I'm a bit uncomfortable about this step)
$$
P(|Y_n-y|>\epsilon|(X_n)_{n \ge 0}) \to 0
$$
everywhere. Since this is a probability, by the bounded convergence theorem, we also have
$$
P(|Y_n-y|>\epsilon) \to 0
$$
without conditioning.

Is this a correct proof?